# Interdependent NPM packages: peerDependency not resolving against "host" package

Tags: npm, node-modules, peer-dependencies

I disovered the hard way today that I need to split a library into two packages; lets call them `CoreLib` and `TestCoreLib`. The `CoreLib` package is a library, the `TestCoreLib` library is the bundle of utilities and actors needs to setup the test environment required to test the `CoreLib` library. The added benefit of splitting this into two packages is that apps built with `CoreLib` can also beneift from use of `TestCoreLib` as it also suffices as a mocking library.

As `TestCoreLib` uses some actors from `CoreLib`, I defined `CoreLib` as a *peerDependency* of `TestCoreLib`.

```json
{
  "name": "TestCoreLib",
  "version": "1.0.0-rc.1",
  "type": "module",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "CoreLib": "^1.0.0-rc.0"
  }
}
```

Conversely, I defined `TestCoreLib` as a *devDependency* of `CoreLib` as `CoreLib` of course has the need of passing its tests before publish.

```json
{
  "name": "CoreLib",
  "version": "1.0.0-rc.1",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "TestCoreLib": "^1.0.0-rc.0"
  }
}
```

Both release candidate packages have been published to NPM successfully and I have setup a third project `DemoApp` that uses both `CoreLib` and `TestCoreLib` successfully.

```json
{
  "name": "DemoApp",
  "version": "1.0.0-rc.1",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "CoreLib": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "TestCoreLib": "^1.0.0-rc.0"
  }
}
```

The problem is now in the development branch of the `CoreLib` project. Tests don't complete complete as the following error is thrown:

> Uncaught Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'CoreLib' imported from /path/to/CoreLib/node_modules/CoreTestLib/lib/index.js

That tells me that `CoreLib` is not being picked up by `TestCoreLib`, even though `TestCoreLib` is in the `node_modules` directory of the `CoreLib` project. The first statement in `TestCoreLib` is an import from `CoreLib`, so I assume the error is being thrown as that import is not being resolved even though it should... right?

I always want the development version of `CoreLib` to be used by `TestCoreLib`, so I am concerned about adding `CoreLib` as a `devDependency` (instead of a `peerDependency`) of `TestCoreLib` as I worry that doing such will lock `CoreLib` into version conflict with its own prior release, but I am honestly confused about what would happen in that context.

The lazy boy moon shot of linking `TestCoreLib` to `CoreLib` does not solve the problem either, so I am obviously missing something fundamental that I would really appreciate your help with.

Do you know of any projects that successfully split their packages off into peerDependencies in such a way that you could refer me to?

Is there an elephant in the room sitting top of me and if so could you tell it to get off so that I can resolve this maddening issue and move on? LMAO

Be safe, well, calm, clear, happy fellow humans. Thanks for considerations.

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room was... [the lazy boy moonshot](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link#see-also) and my misuse of it. My automatic typing fingers told me five minutes ago by adding the scoped package name to it

```sh
$ npm link @emmington/CoreLib
```

`npm link` by itself is insufficient for a symlinking a *scoped package folder*.

[Symlinking a package folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link#see-also)

[Scoped Packaged](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)